# combining results of two REST resources to grouped items in vue-multiselect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am a newbie in javascript / vuejs, I have implemented a vue-multiselect in which I want to have two category groups, 1 that is projects from github and 2nd is the one that are thirdparty projects.

for both I have written code below. It works if I set either one of them
like, either `this.projects = _projects` or `this.projects = thirdParty` but if I concatenate the list `thirdParty` with `_projects` it doesn't work.

```
  mounted() {
 var _projects = [];
   var thirdParty = [];
 axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/projects?placeholder=darwin")
     .then(response => {
       this.selectedBranch = "";
       _projects = [{"projectType": "Github Projects", "grpValues": response.data.projects}]
       console.log("Github" + response.data.projects);
       console.log(_projects);

     })



  axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/thirdparty")
   .then(response => {
   console.log(_projects);
   thirdParty = [{"projectType": "Thirdparty Projects", "grpValues": response.data}]
   _projects.concat(thirdParty);
   this.projects = _projects
   })
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`concat` does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array. Try this instead:

```
_projects = _projects.concat(thirdParty);
```

or, even better, don't mutate `_projects` at all, and instead directly assign to `this.projects`:

```
this.projects = _projects.concat(thirdParty);
```

Or, better than both, use `Promise.all` to add them both at once:

```
async mounted() {
  const [darwinProjectResponse, thirdPartyResponse] = await Promise.all([
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/projects?placeholder=darwin"),
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/thirdparty")
  ]);
  this.projects = [{
    "projectType": "Github Projects",
    "grpValues": darwinProjectResponse.data.projects,
  },{
    "projectType": "Thirdparty Projects",
    "grpValues": thirdPartyResponse.data,
  }];
}
```

Comment: Now I am getting  Network Error saying `Cross Origin Request blocked: The Same Origin policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/thirdparty` Earlier it was working fine, I have set firefox `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` set to false

Comment: That's a completely separate issue, look up other answers on CORS, there are many of them on SO and around the internet.